# Source of a 2D vector skeleton?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resource-recommendations, adobe-flash, adobe-animate

I'm looking for a vector skeleton, preferably with all 206 human bones. I want to be able to stretch and alter the shape of human bones for graphic design purposes. More specifically, I would like to design characters and creatures using the basic human bone structure as a template.

I haven't been able to find a pre-made one and doing it all by hand from scratch would take a very long time. I suppose a bitmap image of all the bones would do as well in a pinch, since I could pretty easily make that vector. If this question is inappropriate, please let me know because I am new to this stackexchange, and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Google "skeleton SVG" - The wikimedia commons link has several you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "skeleton SVG" or "skeleton vector", you should be able to find free sources. Ultimately search in stock images websites, there are plenty of sites where you can buy a vector file for a few bucks.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This answers the question perfectly! Anyway I upvoted.

Comment: Yes, that's the right answer. We may include the word "free".